# org.testng.TestNGException: Cannot inject @Test annotated Method with [class java.lang.String]

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testng

i am getting below error for TestNG. Not sure why

below is complete error:
FAILED: launchB
org.testng.TestNGException:

Cannot inject @Test annotated Method [launchB] with [class java.lang.String].

```
For more information on native dependency injection please refer to http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#native-dependency-injection
at org.testng.internal.Parameters.checkParameterTypes(Parameters.java:244)
at org.testng.internal.Parameters.createParameters(Parameters.java:172)
at org.testng.internal.Parameters.createParameters(Parameters.java:458)
at org.testng.internal.Parameters.handleParameters(Parameters.java:569)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.handleParameters(Invoker.java:1308)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.createParameters(Invoker.java:1036)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1126)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:126)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:744)
at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:602)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:380)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:375)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:340)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:289)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1301)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1226)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1144)
at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1115)
at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:132)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:230)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:76)
```

Below is the code:

```
    public class LaunchBrowser_2 {
WebDriver driver;
String browser = "IE";
@Test
public void launchB(String browser){

    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "D:\\geckodriver\\geckodriver.exe");
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\Chromedriver\\chromedriver.exe");
    System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "D:\\IEDriver\\IEDriverServer.exe");

    if(browser.equals("Mozilla"))
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    else if (browser.equals("Chrome"))
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
    else if (browser.equals("IE")){
        DesiredCapabilities cap = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
        cap.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS, true);
        driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(cap);                               
    }
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    //driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.get("http://www.rediff.com");        
}
```

Comment: Have you checked the link in exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you defined the method `launchB()` you have taken in an argument `String browser`. You just can't supply the `String browser` from the same class as the method `launchB()` is annotated with `@Test`.

### Solution:

The solution would be to accept the argument `String browser` from the `testng.xml`. So you have to do certain modification. Remove/Comment the line `String browser = "IE";`. Add `@Parameters("browser")` just over the `@Test` annotation. Next, move the `System.setProperty` line into respective `if()` blocks. Finally, for your convenience replace `browser.equals()` to `browser.equalsIgnoreCase`. You final code block will look like:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.testng.annotations.Parameters;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class Q45523264_inject 
{
    WebDriver driver;
    @Parameters("browser")
    @Test
    public void launchB(String browser)
    {

        if(browser.equalsIgnoreCase("Mozilla"))
        {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\geckodriver.exe");
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        }
        else if (browser.equalsIgnoreCase("Chrome"))
        {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        }
        else if (browser.equalsIgnoreCase("IE"))
        {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\IEDriverServer.exe");
        DesiredCapabilities cap = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
        cap.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS, true);
        driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(cap);                               
        }
        driver.get("http://www.rediff.com/");  

    }
}
```

Now, you have to convert your program through `Convert to TestNG`. Your `testng.xml` got generated. Next you have pass the argument for `String browser` from the `testng.xml`. You have to pass the parameter either `<parameter name="browser" value="Mozilla"/>` or `<parameter name="browser" value="IE"/>` (now commmented) or `<parameter name="browser" value="Chrome"/>` (now commmented) from the `testng.xml`. Your `testng.xml` will look like:

```html
<suite name="Suite">
  <test name="My Test">
  <parameter name="browser" value="Mozilla"/>
  <!-- <parameter name="browser" value="IE"/> -->
  <!-- <parameter name="browser" value="Chrome"/> -->
    <classes>
      <class name="demo.Q45523264_inject"/>
    </classes>
  </test> <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

Comment: Please stop adding "Let me know if this Answers your Question." to the end of each of your answers. It is nothing but noise/ clutter, and users tend to let you know whether your answer works or not regardless. For more info, see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts